# How can I find value of cell in index detail in other cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel, where I want some calculation to be dynamic in such a way that I want to add two values. For example to calculate A2+A5, I want something like getValue(Z1)+getValue(Z2). Where Z1 has "A2" and Z2 has "A5"

So if I want to change Z1 and Z2 values to say A3 and A4, then it start returning value of A3+A4.

Is it feasible in excel?

Thanks

Comment: r u looking for `INDIRECT()` ?

Comment: Indirect function - [ExcelJet](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-indirect-function) and [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

Comment: Thanks, this seems what I was looking for!